# fgrep with string containing flags

Tags: bash, unix, grep, arguments, zsh

I want to run pipe something to fgrep with many flags:

```
echo "hi" | fgrep -e hi -e bye -e don ...
```

To do this, I want to create the string containing the flags and strings beforehand. Basically, I am trying to do this:

```
STR="-e hi"
STR="${STR} -e bye"
echo "nihibyehi\nhello\nhi" | fgrep ${=STR}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
${=STR}: bad substitution
```

There is definitely a way to do this via fgrep in this manner (using "fgrep ${=STR}"). What is it?

Comment: Why are you doing `${=STR}`? Why not just `${STR}`?

Comment: Based on your comment below, it looks like the only problem is that you're trying to run your - valid - `zsh` code with the _wrong shell_. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

The OP apparently uses `zsh`, but tagged the question only generically as `shell` (suggesting POSIX compatibility).

What likely happened was that he/she tried to run the above `zsh`-specific code using a *different* shell, resulting in the `bad substitution` error - `bash` would give that error, for instance.

When run with `zsh`, the above code DOES work - it uses `zsh`'s string-splitting flag `=` to break the contents of `$STR` into individual words - but it doesn't generalize well:
if the search strings had embedded spaces, for instance, the solution would break.

Below is a **more robust solution** that works in `zsh` as well as in `bash`, plus a solution for POSIX-compatible shells.

---

Assuming you're using **bash** or **zsh**:

Use an **array** to build up your list of arguments, then pass the entire array double-quoted to `fgrep`:

```
STR=('-e' 'hi')
STR+=('-e' 'bye')
printf 'nihibyehi\nhello\nhi\n' | fgrep "${STR[@]}"
```

---

For **POSIX-compatible shells** (if using `bash` or `zsh` is NOT an option), you can write the search strings to a (temporary) file and use the `-f` option to pass it to `fgrep`:

```
echo 'hi' > STRs.txt
echo 'bye' >> STRs.txt
printf 'nihibyehi\nhello\nhi\n' | fgrep -f STRs.txt
```

Comment: DATE="-e .2013-03-26. -e .2013-03-27."; for file in $(ls | fgrep ${=DATE}); do; echo ${file}; done;

Comment: @user1145925: If that works for you, you're likely using `zsh`, and you should tag your question that way. `shell` in a Unix context implies a POSIX-compatible shell, but the feature you're using - the splitting flag `=` - is not. (On a side note, you shouldn't parse command output with `for` - use `while IFS='' read -r ...` instead.)